# Creating a custom field module

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I am trying to create a custom field module for views, but I keep getting this error when I add the field to the view.

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054
>   Unknown column 'views_report_state_field' in 'field list'

This is the code I am using.

#### views_report_state.info

```
name = Views Report State
description = Turns short abbreviated states (ex: TX) into fully readable names (ex: Tx = Texas)
package = Views
core = 7.x

files[] = views/views_report_state_field.inc
```

#### views_report_state.module

```
function views_report_state_views_api($module = NULL, $api = NULL) {
  return array("api" => 3);
}
```

#### views_report_state.views.inc

```
function views_report_state_views_handlers() {
  $handlers = array(
    'info' => array(
      'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'views_report_state'),
    ),
    'handlers' => array(
      'views_report_state_field' => array(
        'parent' => 'views_handler_field',
      ),
    ),
  );
  return $handlers;

function views_report_state_views_data() {
  $data = array();
  $data['views']['views_report_state_field'] = array(
    'title' => t('CRF: Convert US-State Abbreviations'),
    'help' => t('Converts State Abbreviations to their full name'),
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_report_state_field',
    ),
  );
  return $data;
}
```

#### views_report_state_field.inc

```
class views_report_state_field extends views_handler_field {

  function render() {
    return "working!";
  }

}
```

Comment: Try adding an empty `query` method to your handler class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

views_report_state_field.inc

```
class views_report_state_field extends views_handler_field {
  function query() {
    // Query
  }

  function render() {
    return "working!";
  }

}
```